# Frame Rate recommended for Stop Motion?

Tags: building, minifigures

I do Stop Motion with LEGO, (which is just great for SMA) and I was wondering (because you guys are the pros), what frame rate per second, (fps) you would recommend?

I use 15, and occasionally 33. Also I was wondering, how extreme I should take this Stop Motion Animation? Should it just be my hobby, or should I use to get me money?

Comment: IS it good enough to make money from? Would you charge people to watch or just have ads? Take a look at [Battle of the Brick](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFB60NnsGrI).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ideal frame rate is 24 fps due to the brain holding an image for .051... seconds

However in stop motion animation this can be quite tedious and time consuming.

So with that in mind I'd recommend a frame rate of between 15 and 18.

As for your ideas on making money out of it, I'd say go for it.

Comment: The brain holding an image? Not sure I agree with the first sentence - how we experience motion differs a lot from individual to individual and where in our view stuff is actually moving. People in high-speed situations can often tell the difference up to and beyond 100 FPS... not that 100 FPS is a good target for stop-motion though - 15 FPS seems to be the norm.

Comment: I believe that minimatt is talking about persistence of vision (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision)

Comment: @OskarDuveborn Film (at least physical film) is typically projected at 24fps, and television broadcasts were typically in 25fps (PAL) or 30fps (NTSC) (albeit interlaced for 50 or 60 half frames pers second). Disney and Warner Brothers animations were typically drawn "on twos", where each frame would be shown twice resulting in 12-15fps.

Comment: Today almost all displays your content will be shown on are 60 FPS screens, phones, tablets, laptops and HD TVs. While most TVs can sync to a different refresh rate, this requires support from the device that displays the animation, and this will very seldom be done unless in a properly set up home theatre system. As such, an even multiple of 60 will prevent stuttering due to dropped/inserted frames for a 60 FPS display.

Answer (score 2):

The standard frame rate for most LEGO stop motion animations is 15, although this may vary and will be enforced by the video compiling software you use to put your animation together. Less than 15 will cause some frames to be added, while having more may skip a few. This also extends to 30 FPS, although that many frames is very time consuming, hence the 15 frame standard.

Answer (score 0):

The best frame rate depends on what are you making or if you have started only a few times ago. 
If you started now, I recommend 12 FPS to start learning the movements basic.

If you already started months/years ago the best frame rate is 15 FPS. But if you want a really smooth look or something else, use 24.